# SQL Server starts with list of strings

Tags: pymssql

I was previously using MySQL and had a query which used a `REGEXP`. I'm trying to find `site_id`s beginning with certain characters, and used the following:

```
WHERE site_id REGEXP '^(AB|BC|AO|BO|CA|PAF|Z)'
```

Basically trying to find rows where `site_id LIKE 'AB%' OR 'BC%'...`, but because I have quite a few strings to match against, I'd like to do it in a less verbose manner.

Unfortunately SQL Server doesn't seem to like this syntax and I get an error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'REGEXP'.DB-Lib error message 4145, severity 15: General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server

Is there a neat way of doing this without using heaps of `LIKE 'XX%' OR ...`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of `left`, `or`, and `in` to shorten your query.

```
WHERE left(site_id,2) in ( 'AB', 'BC', 'AO', 'BO', 'CA') or left(site_id, 3) = 'PAF' or left(site_id, 1) = 'Z'
```